# Is there any geoserver plugin available to read excel files and displaying values on respective pincode/zipcode areas of Geoserver wms/wfs maps?

Tags: geoserver

I have business data with pincodes in an excel file. Pincode boundaries shapefile is configured in geoserver. zipcode is common field in both of the files.

Could anyone guide me about the plugins availability to read excel files and display respective zipcode business figures on WMS/WFS maps of Geoserver 2.5.2 version with windows 7 (64 bit OS).

If plugins are not available, then how to check multiple parameters using spatial queries to geoserver layers?

ex:- In a zipcode file, age groups, income groups, profession fields are present. If i want to show result of 40-45 age group with annual income greater than 5M from doctors profession on wms/wfs maps. How can i achieve this? Any idea/advise can be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In fact there sort of is an excel plugin for GeoServer in that you can (or could) take the the [GeoTools Community Excel Datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/excel.html) and drop it into GeoServer and it should just work. But it will be quite slow if you have more than a few hundred points.

Sadly GeoTools doesn't build the community modules by default so you'll need to get the sources and build it your self.

One day I might finish it and push it up into supported land and then wrap it as a GeoServer module but to be honest there has been no demand for it in the last 4 years or so. Feel free to let me know how you get on.

Comment: Hi iant, Thankyou for very quick reply. As eblondel conveyed, Excel plugin is currently not available on the specified page for download (build may take time as i need to fix if any errors encountered), but excel plugin is listed under unsupported plugins heading. i will check with alternate option suggested by eblondel...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no Geoserver plugin to READ excel file, only a plugin to export data in Excel WFS output format. The vector datastore extensions available are listed here: http://geoserver.org/release/stable/

What you might do eventually is to join these attribute data (depending on its structure) into the shapefile you mention, and republish it in Geoserver.

If you use a spatial database, you could import both shapefile and tabular data, and proceed to the join either doing a view in the database, or a Geoserver sql view directly in Geoserver.

Now, if the tabular data (stats) you have is larger than the reference data (shapefile), and that you want to map only a piece of the tabular data you have in a flexible way, then the best for you is to use a spatial database, and publish the data as a Geoserver parametrized SQL View layer: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Long story short, this allows you to join your statistical data to your reference GIS layer, but exposing the stats variables (*ie* `age groups`, `income groups`, `profession fields`) you want as custom parameters of your WMS and WFS service. The typical use case of this is to map some piece of statistics (from a large tabular dataset or timeseries) to a reference GIS layer.

Comment: Hi eblondel, Thankyou for guidance. i will check sqlview implementation. As of now, i am using shape files with geocoded tables to get results and display on maps (zipcode is common filed). As you expected, tabular records are more than reference shapefile polygons(80 zipcode polygons & 1300 table records). All polygon features always need to be displayed and when user mouseover on polygon, query should be fired and data will be fetched from excel file/database table for that polygon. As table records are more, i need to sumup values and display results on popup over respective zipcode polygon